# Re-render template on login

Tags: javascript, jquery, templates, meteor, rendering

In navbar I have 2 dropdowns, and one of them is available only if user is logged in (otherwise I hide it with `{{#if currentUser}}`).

For a dropdown to work it should be activated with jquery like this: `$('.somedropdown').dropdown();`.

In meteor:

`Template.navbar.rendered = function () {
   this.$('.somedropdown') .dropdown();
};`

In my case I assigned these classes to dropdowns: `.guest`(for dropdown that is available all the time) and `.useronly`(for that which is available only if user is signed in).

And thus I try to do re-rendering of navbar adding `this.autorun` to `rendered` callback. It checks if user is logged in and should trigger re-rendering accordingly:

`Template.navbar.rendered = function () {
    this.$('.guest').dropdown();
    this.autorun(function() {
        if(Meteor.userId()) {
            $('.useronly').dropdown();
        }
    });
};`

But it does not work.

1. When I first load webpage navbar renders OK without the `.useronly` dropdown.
2. When I sign in the `.useronly` dropdown appears but it is not activated via jquery.
3. If I then run activation code `$('.useronly').dropdown();` in console - the dropdown starts to work. It means the problem is not with jquery code.

`Meteor.userId()` is reactive so I don't get it why `this.autorun` does not thigger re-rendering.

PS If it is important to mention, I use Semantic UI dropdown module http://semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown.html (this is where jquery activation code comes from).

PPS there are already similar questions on stackoverflow but I did not find any appropriate solution from the answers.

Thank you for any help in advance.

**SOLUTION**

By adding console.logs into the code mentioned above I found that autorun actually worked but the jquery code ran before dropdown was actually rendered. So I wrapped autorun function into Meteor.setTimeout():

`Template.header.rendered = function () {
    // activate always available .guest dropdown
    this.$('.guest')
        .dropdown();
    // activate .useronly dropdown if user is logged in
    this.autorun(function() {
        if(Meteor.userId()) {
            Meteor.setTimeout(function() {
                // add 0 delay just to add it last to the event loop
                $('.useronly')
                .dropdown();
            }, 0);
        }
    });
};`

PS also check the neater solution by https://stackoverflow.com/users/2104665/peppe-l-g in answers.

Comment: do you have a repo we can look at?  thx

Comment: thank you, but it is not needed anymore, the issue is solved

Comment: @AlexBuduguru, I think a delay of 0 (just adding it last to the event loop) will be enough.

Comment: @PeppeL-G thanks for mentioning it (edited the code). Nice to know for future cases.
BTW if you compare your and my solutions, what pluses and minuses can you point?

Comment: @AlexBuduguru, I don't know, the code is quite small, so both solutions are pretty easy to understand, but if the code were longer, I would definitely go with my solution. Your solution would be hard to understand if you would use more reactive data sources in the autorun, and I can easily use the destroyed callback to animate something (or whatever) when the user logs out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing your autorun runs before the `{{#if currentUser}}` block in your template is updated, which means `$('.useronly')` won't refer to any element.

I think the Meteor way to solve this is by using an extra template:

```html
<template name="main">
    {{#if currentUser}}
        {{> signedInDropDown}}
    {{/if}}
</template>

<template name="signedInDropDown">
    <!-- Your drop down here. -->
</template>
```

```js
Template['signedInDropDown'].rendered = function(){
    this.$('.useronly').dropdown();
}
```

Comment: Yes. You are right. The jquery code in autorun was actually runned before the dropdown appeared. I solved it by whapping of autorun function with Meteor.setTimeout (see update in the question).

But your solution seems to be more "meteorish" and elegant. I will try to do it like you suggest and if it works I will accept the answer.